# Improving performance when rendering animated scatterplot using Plotly Express

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I’m currently using Plotly Express to render an animated scatterplot using data that is roughly 120,000 rows (it is an animated football match). It takes about 1/2 hour to render just 50,000 rows at the moment (I dare not try the entire thing). Then I’m displaying it using Dash. Is there any way to improve the initial HTML rendering performance prior to displaying it in Dash? Here’s my current code:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x="X", y="Y", color="teamId", hover_name="NickName", animation_frame="GameTime", animation_group="NickName", range_x=[-4,110], range_y=[-4,72], size='size', size_max=8, width=900, height=700, color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map, title="Match Demo")
# Remove side scale and hide zero and gridlines
fig.update_layout(
    coloraxis_showscale=False,
    xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False),
    yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False),
)
# Disable axis ticks and labels
fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False)
fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='')
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='')
image_file = 'WhitePitch.png'
image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),image_file)

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(image_path)

fig.add_layout_image(
        dict(
            source=img,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            x=-5,
            y=72,
            sizex=115,
            sizey=77,
            sizing="stretch",
            opacity=0.5,
            layer="below")
)

# Sets background to white vs grey
fig.update_layout(template="plotly_white")
```

Would really appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered splitting your data into frames as a pre processing step? You could then feed them one at a time to the graph via a dash callback triggered by an interval component.

Comment: Actually I was about to do that in order to add an additional layer in the form of a geometric shape that overlays the scatterplot marks. I planned on using a dataframe groupby command to do that. However, after that, I'm going to have to look up how to feed them into the graph via dash. Any hints on how to do a "callback triggered by an interval component"? I have not tried that. In fact, this is my first crack at using Plotly in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to improve the performance here. First for foremost I don't believe you need to display 120k data points right away. A better approach is to display a high level grouped scatter chart first and then you can expand the detail based on user selection.

There are a number of Dash input options that can be used to achieve this level of interactivity

To further improve performance I would only create a datatable with the data required to plot the current view. Then as the user drills down load further data as required. This will reduce the memory consumption of your app and load time

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. There is not much user mark selection activity involved in this particular scenario (e.g. no drill-downs). Using Dash I just hit play and the scatterplot marks are constantly moving around (as players naturally would since this is an animated sport scenario). So far I have a 20-minute clip working flawlessly. The problem, of course, is that the game is 90 minutes long and I'm not able to render it all currently via my python script. It just stalls and I have to kill it. Perhaps Plotly was not really developed with such long animation periods in mind?

Comment: OK understood. Thats an interesting use case basically using scatterplot to animate. How about reducing the frequency of the updates? That could halve the size of the data.

Another option is to remove entries where the location of the player hasn't changed or run an algorithm to remove entries where the movement is less than a threshold

Comment: Good ideas. I've already downsampled the data by quite a large factor (one out of every 5-8 frames I think), but it's still relatively smooth despite such a reduction. Further reduction could result in some ugly jitter. I was hoping that there was a setting like webgl that would help, but when I tried that it broke the graph quite badly - as in nothing displayed :-)